# A certain quotient of a (not necessarily solvable) finite group is solvable

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, which is not necessarily solvable. I am trying to prove the following statement:

> There exists a smallest normal subgroup $N(G) \lhd G$ such that $G/N(G)$ is solvable

I can prove this if I choose N(G) to be the intersection of all normal subgroups $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N$ is normal. This is because if $G/N$ and $G/M$ are solvable, then $G/(N \cap M)$ is solvable (and then proceeding with induction).

Am I always guaranteed to find at least one normal subgroup of $G$ such that this is true?

Comment: You could always take $N(G)=G$. Then $G/N(G)$ is certainly solvable.

Comment: Note that this does not hold for infinite groups. If you take finite groups $G_n$ that are solvable of solvability length exactly $n$, and let $G=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$, which is not solvable; then $N_m=\prod_{n=m}^{\infty} G_n$ is normal with $G/N$ solvable, but their intersection is trivial.